# Is it possible to have an optional field in an Avro schema (i.e. the field does not appear at all in the .json file)?

Tags: json, avro

Is it possible to have an optional field in an Avro schema (i.e. the field does not appear at all in the .JSON file)?

In my Avro schema, I have two fields:

```
{"name": "author", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
{"name": "importance", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
```

And in my JSON files those two fields can exist or not.

However, when they do not exist, I receive an error (e.g. when I test such a JSON file using avro-tools command line client):

```
Expected field name not found: author
```

I understand that as long as the **field name** exists in a JSON, it can be `null`, or a `string` value, but what I'm trying to express is something like "this JSON is valid if the those field names **do not exist**, OR if they exist and they are null or string".

Is this possible to express in an Avro schema? If so, how?

Comment: I faced to the same problem. Have you found solution?

Comment: @red1ynx unfortunately no. I still can't express a totally optional JSON field using Avro schema.

Comment: I've struggled with this too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193729/avro-how-can-i-use-default-fields-when-i-dont-know-the-exact-schema-that-the

Comment: you may want to add some code on how you are parsing from json to avro

Answer (score 47):

you can define the default attribute as undefined example.
so the field can be skipped.

```
{ 
   "name": "first_name",
   "type": "string",
   "default": "undefined"
},
```

Also all field are manadatory in avro.
if you want it to be optional, then union its type with null.
example:

```
{
    "name": "username",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ],
    "default": null
},
```

Comment: Isn't OP using exactly the same as in this answer?

Answer (score 15):

According to avro specification this is possible, using the **default** attribute.

See https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html

> default: A default value for this field, **used when reading instances that lack this field** (optional). Permitted values depend on the field's schema type, according to the table below. Default values for union fields correspond to the first schema in the union.

At the example you gave, you do add the default attribute with value "null", so this should work. However, supporting this depends also on the library you use for reading the avro message (there are libraries at c,c++,python,java,c#,ruby etc.). Maybe (probably) the library you use lack this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing a the type ("null" or "string") as a key in the object to be serialized, or just trying to serialize a bare object?

Avro implements [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) and will not perform type inference to decide which type an object is. This means that you have to provide a type tag.

I am testing with Node and [avro-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avro-js). The following works:

```
const avro = require( "avro-js" );
const schema = {
    type: "record", name: "test", fields: [
        {
            "name": "author", "type": ["null", "string"],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "importance", "type": ["null", "string"],
            "default": null
        },
    ]
};
const s = avro.parse( schema );
s.toBuffer( {
    author: { null: null },
    importance: { null: null }
} ).toString();
// '\x00\x00'
s.toBuffer( {
    author: { string: 'Homer' },
    importance: { string: '1' }
} ).toString();
// '\x02\nHomer\x02\x021'
```

I find that I *can* serialize an empty object because default values are provided:

```
s.toBuffer( {} ).toString();
// '\x00\x00'
```

However, this may be implementation-specific. Can you provide reproduction instructions so we can help further?

Answer (score 0):

Using the **default** attribute with `null` value or union type `[null, orignal_type]`.

- value `undefined` is not supported -> [docs](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/)

In case of object it should look like this:

```js
const avro = require('avsc');

const yourSchema = avro.Type.forSchema({
  type: 'record',
  name: 'parent_record',
  fields: [
    { name: 'field_1', type: ['null', 'string'], default: null },
    { 
      name: 'optional_object_type', 
      type: ['null', {
        type: 'record',
        name: 'optional_record',
        fields: [{ name: 'sub_field', type: 'string' }]
      }],
      default:null
    }
  ]
});
```